# How to inherate a Class of type Flow in prefect?

Tags: python, prefect

I currently have a workflow defined within a simple python class. In this class I have defined a separate method for each task. I now start the ETL via class.run().

```py
class Main():
   ...
   def _read_data(self, fname: str):
      """ read data from file """
      ....
      return data

   def _process_data(self, data):
      """ process data """
      ...
     return results

   def run(self, fname: str):
      """ define ETL"""
      data = self._read_data(fname)
      results = self._proess_data(data)
```

I now have different data which should be processed by the ETL. So I inherate a new class from the Main class and overwrite the read_data method. This way I have a clean code structure and would like to transfer the method to Prefect.

```py
class B(Main):
   def _read_data(self, fname:str):
      """ read csv file, seperator not , but \t """

     return data
```

I could define classes of the type Task for the individual tasks. Can I also define a flow class where I replace the read_data method for different data? Does anyone have a comprehensible example for me?

Does it perhaps make more sense that I pass a certain number of parameters to the flow and a dynamic flow is started depending on these parameters? This way I could control the method for reading in the data via the parameters, the rest of the ETL is fixed.

Thx, Markus

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you rewrite your Prefect 1.0 flow structure to fit the functional API. Given that Prefect 2.0 (i.e. the future version of Prefect) will no longer support [the imperative class-based API](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/can-i-define-my-tasks-as-classes-rather-than-functions/54), rewriting your flow now will make your custom code compatible with the future Prefect versions.

Apart from making your code compatible with future versions of Prefect, you will gain much more observability this way. Why? Currently, both classes Main and B only give you information about a "big" ETL job - if this fails, it will only give you information that your ETL failed without telling you which part of it caused the issue (whether something went wrong when extracting, transforming or loading the data). [This documentation page](https://docs.prefect.io/core/tutorial/02-etl-flow.html#etl-with-prefect) provides more background about that including examples of how you can apply that in your Prefect flow.

But since your question asked explicitly for the imperative API, every class inherited from `Task` has a `.run()` method that you can override and this method is what gets invoked when you call the task in your flow.

Based on the problem you described, functional programming seems to be the right way of approaching it as in each flow you can call a different functional task specifying how to read the data instead of overwriting that on a Task or Flow class. You mentioned you would like to parameterize it to determine which task to run depending on some dynamically supplied Parameter value. This is possible using the `case` task:

```py
from random import random

from prefect import task, Flow, case

@task
def check_condition():
    return random() < .5

@task
def action_if_true():
    return "I am true!"

@task
def action_if_false():
    return "I am false!"

@task
def another_action(val):
    print(val)


with Flow("conditional-branches") as flow:
    cond = check_condition()

    with case(cond, True):
        val = action_if_true()
        another_action(val)

    with case(cond, False):
        val = action_if_false()
        another_action(val)
```

[This page](https://docs.prefect.io/core/idioms/conditional.html) explains this conditional logic more and [this blog post](https://www.prefect.io/blog/how-to-make-your-data-pipelines-more-dynamic-using-parameters-in-prefect/) dives deeper into parametrization.